# Stripe checkout - IE popup is blocked on second payment

Tags: javascript, stripe-payments, stripe.js

O/S: BrowserStack Live

Browser: IE11

I am using Stripe checkout with js sdk to display a popup when the user clicks a button. The code is as follows:

```
Payment.prototype = {
    pay: function (options, callback) {
        let tokenTriggered = false;
        _handler = StripeCheckout.configure({
            key: Constants[Constants.ENV].STRIPE_KEY,
            image: 'image.jpg',
            locale: 'auto',
            token: function token(token) {
                tokenTriggered = true;
                const data = {
                    stripeToken: token.id,
                    stripeEmail: token.email,
                    amount: options.amount,
                    currency: CURRENCY,
                    capture: options.capture
                };
                $.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    data: JSON.stringify(data),
                    contentType: 'application/json',
                    url: '/api/stripe',
                    success: function success(charge) {
                        callback(null, charge);
                    },
                    error: function error(error) {
                        callback(error.responseText);
                    }
                });
            },
            closed: function () {
                if (!tokenTriggered) {
                    // close button click behavior goes here
                    callback(1);
                }
            }
        });
    },
    open: function (amount, name, description) {
        // Open Checkout with further options:
        _handler.open({
            name: name,
            description: description,
            zipCode: true,
            currency: 'aud',
            amount: amount
        });
    }
};
```

The 'pay' function is invoked followed by the 'open' function. The workflow of my app requires the user to pay for stuff twice in one session. In IE11, no Stripe popup is displayed on the second payment. Any ideas?

The following url https://stripe.com/docs/checkout explains that the 'handler.open' code shouldn't  be in a callback which it isn't.

The console error is: "SCRIPT70: Permission denied".

** EDIT 07/03/2017 **

This error is only occurring when: a payment is made, another page is navigated to, then another payment is attempted.

Comment: I tried to repro your error in a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/testtestjstest/m6d180ek/18/) and couldn't -- Checkout was still opening twice in IE11.  Can you make a JSFiddle with the error for me to look at?

Comment: @postmoderngres thanks for setting up the fiddle, I added more info about my situation.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this by initialising the StripeCheckout only once when the site is loaded. I then moved the functionality from "StripeCheckout.configure" into the "handler.open" function and invoked that whenever I need a payment.

```
    init: function () {
        _handler = StripeCheckout.configure({
            key: Constants[Constants.ENV].STRIPE_KEY,
            image: 'image.jpg',
            locale: 'auto'
        });
    },
    open: function (options, callback) {
        let tokenTriggered = false;
        // Open Checkout with further options:
        _handler.open({
            name: 'An app',
            description: options.description,
            zipCode: true,
            currency: CURRENCY,
            amount: options.amount,
            token: function token(token) {
                tokenTriggered = true;
                const data = {
                    stripeToken: token.id,
                    stripeEmail: token.email,
                    amount: options.amount,
                    currency: CURRENCY,
                    capture: options.capture
                };
                $.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    data: JSON.stringify(data),
                    contentType: 'application/json',
                    url: '/api/stripe',
                    success: function success(charge) {
                        // _instantiated = true;
                        callback(null, charge);
                    },
                    error: function error(error) {
                        callback(error.responseText);
                    }
                });
            },
            closed: function () {
                if (!tokenTriggered) {
                    // close button click behavior goes here
                    callback(1);
                }
            }
        });
    },
```